# Django rest framework IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models: Contain, Container and Integration. Container and Contain inherit from the Product model. There is a manyToMany relationship with integration.

```
class Contain(Product):
    typeCard = models.ForeignKey(TypeCard, related_name="typeOfCad", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.ForeignKey(StateCard, related_name="stateCard", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.serialNumber
```

```
class Container(Product):
    coffret = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="coffrets", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cards = models.ManyToManyField(Contain, through ="Integration")
```

```
class Integration(models.Model):
    Box = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Card = models.ForeignKey(Contain, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_integration = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_desintegration = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class ContainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contain
        fields = ProductSerializer.Meta.fields + ('typeCard', "state")
```

```
class UraContainerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UraContainer
        fields = ProductSerializer.Meta.fields + ("name",'ura_coffret','cards')
```

```
class IntegrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Card = ContainSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Integration
        fields = ('id', 'Box', 'Card', "date_integration", "date_desintegration")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        cards_data = validated_data.pop('uraCard')
        integration = Integration.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for card_data in cards_data:
            Contain.objects.create(integration=integration, **card_data)
        return integration
```

But I have an error:

> IntegrityError at /api/products/integration/
>   null value in column "Card_id" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 2019-07-30, 2, null, null).

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Have you changed your models when there was an `Integration` object in your database?

Comment: No, morever i deleted all of the databas and i did a new migration